# Percentage & GROUP BY

Tags: sqlite

I'm currently working with a collisions dataset which provides all cases that occur in a given day. The dataset is a sqlite database.

My first instinct was to get the totals for a given day, where the output looked something like:

| collision_date | SUM(severe_injury_count) | SUM(injured_victims) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001-02-20 | 19 | 785 |
| 2001-02-20 | 12 | 697 |
| 2001-02-20 | 28 | 823 |
| 2001-02-20 | 29 | 871 |

The above example is the output of the below query:

```
SELECT collision_date, SUM(severe_injury_count),SUM(injured_victims)
FROM collisions c
GROUP BY collision_date
LIMIT 50,100;
```

I wanted to calculate a percentage of severe_injury_count/injured_victims, I thought it would be straightforward, therefore I attempted running this query (with a few variations of how I might have calc. the % - once I noticed it wasn't giving me what I intended):

```
SELECT 
   collision_date, 
   SUM(severe_injury_count/injured_victims) AS chance_being_sever_injured,
   SUM(severe_injury_count),
   SUM(injured_victims),
   (severe_injury_count/injured_victims)*100,
   (SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims))*100
FROM collisions c 
GROUP BY collision_date;
```

But the output I've been given does do the calculation as I might have expected, giving me results like:

| collision_date | chance_being_sever_injured | SUM(severe_injury_count) | SUM(injured_victims) | (severe_injury_count/injured_victims)*100 | (SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims))*100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001-02-20 | 13 | 19 | 785 | NULL | 0 |
| 2001-02-20 | 5 | 12 | 697 | NULL | 0 |
| 2001-02-20 | 17 | 28 | 823 | 0 | 0 |
| 2001-02-20 | 18 | 29 | 871 | NULL | 0 |

I checked the variable types and they are all integers and not strings, so I would have expected to have the actual percentages calculated.

Given the output results, I believe that I'm missing something fundamental when doing this type of operation.

I also tried using FORMAT(), but the output were all zero's as well...

> FORMAT((SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims))*100,2)

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time and feedback.

---

**Implementing suggestions, hence extending initial post:**

I tried the following as well:

```
SELECT collision_date, SUM(severe_injury_count),SUM(injured_victims),CAST(SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims) AS DECIMAL)
FROM collisions c
GROUP BY collision_date
LIMIT 50,100;
```

Tried also to exclude possible NULL's by:

```
SELECT collision_date, SUM(severe_injury_count),SUM(injured_victims),CAST(SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims) AS DECIMAL)
FROM collisions c WHERE severe_injury_count IS NOT NULL OR  injured_victims IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY collision_date
LIMIT 50,100;

SELECT collision_date, SUM(severe_injury_count),SUM(injured_victims),CAST(SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims) AS DECIMAL)
FROM collisions c WHERE severe_injury_count > 0 OR  injured_victims > 0 
GROUP BY collision_date
LIMIT 50,100;
```

All the above alternatives give me 0 as values for the "percentage" column I'm trying to calculate.

Also attempted to coerce the type for a given column as suggested by @easleyfixed like so:

```
SELECT collision_date, SUM(severe_injury_count),SUM(injured_victims),CAST(SUM(CAST(severe_injury_count AS INT))/SUM(CAST(injured_victims AS INT)) AS DECIMAL)
FROM collisions c WHERE severe_injury_count > 0 OR  injured_victims > 0 
GROUP BY collision_date;
```

---

**Expanding on @nnichols & @easleyfixed suggestions**

To better illustrate the data, running:

```
SELECT collision_date,COUNT(*)
FROM collisions c 
GROUP BY collision_date;
```

Gives me (represents the number of records for a given date):

| collision_date | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 2001-01-01 | 1000 |
| 2001-01-02 | 1330 |
| 2001-01-03 | 1329 |
| 2001-01-04 | 1346 |
| 2001-01-05 | 1457 |
| etc | etc |

I therefore expanded the query to try and include what I'm trying to assess.

```
SELECT collision_date,COUNT(*),SUM(severe_injury_count),SUM(injured_victims),
SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims) AS chance_being_sever_injured
FROM collisions c 
GROUP BY collision_date;
```

Outputs:

| collision_date | COUNT(*) | SUM(severe_injury_count) | SUM(injured_victims) | SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims) AS chance_being_sever_injured |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001-01-01 | 1000 | 37 | 676 | 0 |
| 2001-01-02 | 1330 | 30 | 797 | 0 |
| 2001-01-03 | 1329 | 28 | 793 | 0 |
| 2001-01-04 | 1346 | 23 | 758 | 0 |
| 2001-01-05 | 1457 | 30 | 836 | 0 |
| etc | etc | etc | etc | etc |

I double checked the database types and the ones with columns are INT but the collision_date is actually set as "TEXT".

For Sh*t and giggles I did:

```
SELECT CAST(collision_date AS DATE),COUNT(*),SUM(severe_injury_count),SUM(injured_victims),
SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims) AS chance_being_sever_injured
FROM collisions c 
GROUP BY collision_date;
```

| CAST(collision_date AS DATE) | COUNT(*) | SUM(severe_injury_count) | SUM(injured_victims) | SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims) AS chance_being_sever_injured |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2,001 | 1000 | 37 | 676 | 0 |
| 2,001 | 1330 | 30 | 797 | 0 |
| 2,001 | 1329 | 28 | 793 | 0 |
| 2,001 | 1346 | 23 | 758 | 0 |
| 2,001 | 1457 | 30 | 836 | 0 |
| etc | etc | etc | etc | etc |

Also attempting to coerce NULL's into 0 as also suggested.

```
SELECT collision_date ,COUNT(*),SUM(IFNULL(severe_injury_count,0)),SUM(IFNULL(injured_victims,0)),
SUM(IFNULL(severe_injury_count,0))/SUM(IFNULL(injured_victims,0)) AS chance_being_sever_injured
FROM collisions c 
GROUP BY collision_date;
```

Outputs:

| collision_date | COUNT(*) | SUM(severe_injury_count) | SUM(injured_victims) | SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims) AS chance_being_sever_injured |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001-01-01 | 1000 | 37 | 676 | 0 |
| 2001-01-02 | 1330 | 30 | 797 | 0 |
| 2001-01-03 | 1329 | 28 | 793 | 0 |
| 2001-01-04 | 1346 | 23 | 758 | 0 |
| 2001-01-05 | 1457 | 30 | 836 | 0 |
| etc | etc | etc | etc | etc |

I'm truly baffled...

------ EDIT ----

When I initially composed the question I was under the impression sqlite functions were compatible with MySQl. Hence the confusion of why my attempts give "strange" results.

Once I figured the functions don't work the same way, then using the correct syntax got the desired outcome.

Comment: Try to CAST as DECIMAL or perhaps FLOAT depending.

Comment: @easleyfixed - thanks for the reply. I've tried: "CAST((SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims))*100 AS float)" as well as "CAST((SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims))*100 AS DECIMAL)", but the output is 0 for both cases.

Comment: I do see some `NULL` values in the results, and those are not numeric values...

Comment: That is strange as NULL is not numeric as you said .. does this link give you any insight?
https://database.guide/format-a-number-as-a-percentage-in-mysql/#:~:text=In%20MySQL%2C%20we%20can%20format,percent%20sign%20as%20the%20second.

Comment: @easleyfixed thanks for the link but that isn't what I'm looking for.... I'm not worried about having the column output a value with the "%" sign, I'm trying to figure out why isn't the calculations isn't being done as well as trying to figure out what is the correct way to do that kind of operation when executing a query. The dataset can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/alexgude/california-traffic-collision-data-from-switrs

Comment: @Luuk yes I believe that is the "root" cause, but my issue is trying to figure out where that "NULL" is coming from... Take first row of the second "output", 2001-02-20 - column: chance_being_sever_injured gives 13 which makes no sense. The SUM(severe_injury_count) and SUM(injured_victims) have values 19/785 respectively. So for the last column of the second output I would have expected, SUM(severe_injury_count)/SUM(injured_victims))*100 to have been (19/785)*100 = 2.42 and I get NULL if I do "(severe_injury_count/injured_victims)*100" which I did as an eg. for testing only, I know it is wrong

Comment: Ok another thing you try is to convert the datatypes on use, such as the case where we assume the numbers are going to be integers (such as 200 people per day), so Cast as INT that number before you use it EVEN if its already an INT, and the point of this is at least in the case of the NULLS they would now at least show up as 0.  Not the solution per say but perhaps moving us in the correct direction to find out why the nulls exist.

Comment: Have you tried running through the rows using an ISNULL(column) and just see where and how many there are to see if you can figure out the source  of the null or if there is not a single one in the database and its only giving you null as a result of your formula.

Comment: Which RDBMS and version are you running? You cannot `CAST` to `INT` in MySQL. You did not answer my previous question about your multiple instances of the same date when that is the column you are grouping by.

Comment: @nnichols sorry for the delay. I'm using SQLite as deployed on a DBeaver RDBMS.
You are correct, the `2001-02-20` multiple times was an oversight of me trying to represent the output. The database types of columns sever_injury_count and inured_victim are INT. Please refer to the additional comments I've added to the body of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL and SQLite are definitely not the same thing! I have updated the tag on your question.

> Integer divide yields an integer result, truncated toward zero. [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#:%7E:text=Integer%20divide%20yields%20an%20integer%20result%2C%20truncated%20toward%20zero.)

You need to cast to `REAL` or `FLOAT` for the division to work on SQLite:

```sql
SELECT
    collision_date,
    SUM(severe_injury_count),
    SUM(injured_victims),
    ROUND(CAST(SUM(severe_injury_count) AS REAL) / CAST(SUM(injured_victims) AS REAL) * 100, 2)
FROM collisions
GROUP BY collision_date
```

The NULLS observed in one of your tests were the result of division by 0 (zero).

Comment: that did the trick, I wasn't aware that SQLite did not behave as MySQL. Thanks for the feedback and assistance.